# Compare tuples on basis of a field in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

```
(ABC,****,tool1,12)
(ABC,****,tool1,10)
(ABC,****,tool1,13)
(ABC,****,tool2,101)
(ABC,****,tool3,11)
```

Above is input data

Following is my dataset in pig.

> Schema is : Username,ip,tool,duration

I want to add duration of same tools

Output

```
(ABC,****,tool1,35)
(ABC,****,tool2,101)
(ABC,****,tool3,11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GROUP BY and use SUM on the duration.

```
A = LOAD 'data.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (Username:chararray,ip:chararray,tool:chararray,duration:int);
B = GROUP A BY (Username,ip,tool);
C = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN(group) AS (Username,ip,tool),SUM(A.duration);
DUMP C;
```